# Font not loading in Monaca onsen ui

Tags: css, cordova, monaca

Hi I have just started developing in Monaca IDE and I can't seem to implement fonts in my phonegap app.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "customfont";
    src: url("components/monaca-onsenui/css/font_awesome/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("opentype");   
        /* Make sure you defined the correct path, which is related to
            the location of your file `my_css.css` */ 
    }
    body {
        font-family: "customfont";
        font-size:30px;
    }
```

This is the css for the font that i want to use, and it is not implemented...

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the URL is correct? Is the font file loaded correctly?

The following code should work:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/font/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: '30px';
}
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/XbWzMV

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't see why it shouldn't work if the font file is correctly loaded.

Comment: i am using chrome. when i load into the monaca debugger it cant work

Comment: Please be more clear. Is it working in Chrome but not in the Monaca Debugger?

Comment: how do u check in chrome?